# How do I link the pigpio library in a cmake file?

Tags: c++, makefile, raspberry-pi3, gpio, i2c

I'm setting up an i2c communication between a raspberry and a micro-controller but I have some troubles to link the pigpio library to my program.

if I run a test program with the following command, everything works

```
g++ main.cpp -lpthread -lpigpio -0 main
```

which line should I add in my CMakeFiles.txt to make it work?

Comment: Please show your CMakeFiles.txt

Answer (score 0):

The pigpio library comes with some cmake utilities that will show you [how to include](https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio/blob/master/util/Findpigpio.cmake) pigpio in your project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how should I use this file ? I tried to include it in my CMakeFiles.txt, the cmake .. command is working fine but i have the same errors after compiling the program

Comment: @leo0617 a little late to the party but for those (like me) still getting used to cmake, check this out, turns out these files are called "modules" and lots of libraries publish them to make it easier, here's how to use them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529186/what-is-the-right-place-for-findxxx-cmake-files-for-locally-compiled-libs